# Paint on QGraphicsItem with mouse in PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, pyside6

I am trying to create a annotation tool for segmentation. My idea is to create QGrahicsView and QGraphicsScene, then `additem` the image and the mask to the scene. So far I was able to overlay the mask on the image, but have not figured out yet to paint on the mask.

My code for testing:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QFileDialog,
    QStyle,
    QColorDialog,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsPixmapItem,
)


from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Slot, QStandardPaths, QObject
from PySide6.QtGui import (
    QMouseEvent,
    QPaintEvent,
    QPen,
    QAction,
    QPainter,
    QColor,
    QPixmap,
    QIcon,
    QKeySequence,
)

from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

import sys

loader = QUiLoader() #set up loader object

image_path =r"image.jpg"
mask_path=r"mask.png"

class UserInterface(QObject): #An object wrapping around our ui
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = loader.load("paint3.ui", None)
        self.ui.setWindowTitle("Painter3")

        self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.mask_opcity = 0.8

    def show(self):
        self.ui.show()
    
    def do_something(self):

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        image = QPixmap(image_path)
        img_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(image)
        scene.addItem(img_item)

        mask = QPixmap(mask_path)
        msk_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(mask)
        msk_item.setOpacity(self.mask_opcity)
        scene.addItem(msk_item)

        self.ui.grapView.setScene(scene)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = UserInterface()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

Image without any paint.
[image: Original image without mask/paint]

Manually paint the puppy with mouse.
[image: image+mask]

This is how the exported mask should look like. Exported format should be *.png.
[image: mask]

Comment: For the painting part, you *probably* need to override event handlers like `mouseMoveEvent()` on a subclass of QGraphicsPixmapItem, but there are a lot of possible and very different approaches to do so, and your question is a bit vague on the point: what do you want to draw? are those lines, shapes, curves, etc? For the masking, you probably need to use the [`setMask()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html#setMask) function of QPixmap (probably along with `createMaskFromColor()`). Note that only one question per post is allowed, so decide to focus on one problem and eventually create another post.

Comment: @musicamante I added an example, I hope the question is clear enough. I also removed the other question.

Comment: So you don't have the mask, you want to "paint" in order to actually create one, right? In that case, the "mask" item doesn't need to be a QGraphicsPixmapItem, it can be a QGraphicsPathItem that supports mouse events and adds new "regions" to itself, and when you're done you can export the mask by creating a new QPixmap and use the item's `path()` to draw on the pixmap using a QPainter.

Comment: In some cases, I might need to load masks (for viewing or for modification purpose). So for the first image above, I see it as 'empty mask' (mask without any painting), and then I may handle all cases with the same method with QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Comment: I would still use QGraphicsPathItem for the mask as it's more flexible and can easily work with QRegion. You can then "load" masks using the QPixmap functions indicated in my first comment and update the path with them: QPixmap provides `createHeuristicMask()` and `createMaskFromColor()`, both of which return a QBitmap, then you can add it to the path by using `addRegion()` since `QRegion()` has a QBitmap constructor.

Comment: @musicamante could you provide a minimum working sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to use a QGraphicsPixmapItem for this purpose, it may not be efficient, since it would require to continuously draw on a new QPixmap based on the existing one whenever the mask changes.

Instead, a QGraphicsPathItem subclass may be preferred, since it offers some benefits that can also improve performance at some level. Most importantly, it supports QRegion, which are pixel-based areas that are simpler and more appropriate for image editing.

A simple implementation requires that `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseMoveEvent()` handlers are implemented in that item, but this also requires to consider another important aspect: like most shape-based items, its *boundaries* are only within the visible, drawn areas, so we need to ensure that **both** its `boundingRect()` and `shape()` functions return the full rectangle that represents the mask, even if it's empty.

The subclass will then create a QPainterPath based on the actual regions that are going to be drawn by using the mouse. In order to achieve this, we start with an empty `QRegion()` and use its functions to add (or remove) new areas to it; then, every time the overall region is updated, we create a new QPainterPath, add the overall region, and call `setPath()` on the item.

By using the operators and helper functions of QRegion we can easily add new areas: the `|` operator *merges* the original region with a new one, while the `subtracted` function does the opposite.

In order to set an existing mask, we can replace the current region with a new one generated by QPixmap functions:

```
pixmap = QPixmap('mask.png')
mask = pixmap.createHeuristicMask()
# alternatively, createMaskFromColor(<some QColor>)

path = QPainterPath()
path.addRegion(QRegion(mask))
self.setPath(path)
```

To get the mask, we just create a new QPixmap based on the current size, *clear* it (important!), create a QPainter for it, set the current region as the *clip region* and fill the full rectangle with the color (which will be clipped to the mask).

Here is a basic implementation that also allows to "erase" the current mask by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier.

```py
class MaskItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    _showMask = False
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self._boundingRect = QRectF(QPointF(), QSizeF(size))
        self._shape = QPainterPath()
        self._shape.addRect(self._boundingRect)
        self.region = QRegion()

        super().__init__()

        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.PenStyle.NoPen))
        self.setBrush(QColor(255, 80, 255, 127))

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect

    def shape(self): # required for mouse event detection
        return self._shape

    def getMask(self):
        pm = QPixmap(self.size)
        pm.fill(Qt.GlobalColor.black)
        qp = QPainter(pm)

        qp.setClipRegion(self.region)
        qp.fillRect(pm.rect(), Qt.GlobalColor.magenta)
        qp.end()

        return pm

    def addRegionAtPos(self, pos):
        pos = pos.toPoint()
        rect = QRect(pos.x() - 10, pos.y() - 10, 20, 20)
        self.region |= QRegion(rect, QRegion.RegionType.Ellipse)
        self.rebuild()

    def removeRegionAtPos(self, pos):
        pos = pos.toPoint()
        rect = QRect(pos.x() - 10, pos.y() - 10, 20, 20)
        self.region = self.region.subtracted(
            QRegion(rect, QRegion.RegionType.Ellipse))
        self.rebuild()

    def rebuild(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRegion(self.region)
        self.setPath(path)

    def setMask(self, pixmap):
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            self.region = QRegion(pixmap.createHeuristicMask())
            self.rebuild()

    def showMask(self, show):
        if self._showMask != show:
            self._showMask = show
            if show:
                self.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 127))
            else:
                self.setBrush(QColor(255, 80, 255, 127))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier:
            self.removeRegionAtPos(event.pos())
        else:
            self.addRegionAtPos(event.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier:
            self.removeRegionAtPos(event.pos())
        else:
            self.addRegionAtPos(event.pos())

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget=None):
        if self._showMask:
            negative = QRegion(QRect(QPoint(), self.size)).subtracted(self.region)
            qp.save()
            qp.setClipRegion(negative)
            qp.fillRect(opt.rect, Qt.GlobalColor.black)
            qp.restore()
        super().paint(qp, opt, widget)


class MaskMaker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        
        pixmap = QPixmap('base.jpg')
        self.pixmap = self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.maskItem = MaskItem(pixmap.size())
        self.scene.addItem(self.maskItem)

        self.toggleButton = QPushButton('Show mask', checkable=True)
        self.openButton = QPushButton('Open mask')
        self.exportButton = QPushButton('Export mask')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        toolLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(toolLayout)
        toolLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton)
        toolLayout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        toolLayout.addWidget(self.exportButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.toggleButton.toggled.connect(self.maskItem.showMask)
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.exportButton.clicked.connect(self.export)

    def open(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open mask', '', '*.png')
        if path:
            self.maskItem.setMask(QPixmap(path))

    def export(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Export mask', '', '*.png')
        if path:
            self.maskItem.getMask().save(path)
```

Comment: May I know what event will trigger the `paint` function of `MaskItem`?

Comment: The scene is normally updated by the view, eventually required by any object in the scene that requires repainting. So, it's the scene that queries each item about their visibility and eventually calls their `paint()`.

Comment: if the file mask.png has multiple color, says red and green, am I able to load the mask with the colors retained instead of changing all of them to a single color (magenta)?

Comment: @vuict with all due respect, I'd say that I've already helped you **a lot**. I strongly suggest you to take your time, *analyze* the code above and *study* the documentation about all classes and functions used in it. Then consider what you got, what you need to do, and how it could be achieved.

Comment: @musicanmante apology that my comment let you feel I weren't spend effort on it. I did some testing earlier including `QImage` method for setting the black pixels to transparent. And I just confirmed `createHeuristicMask` can only return monochrome bitmap, and I think I can fix it. Thanks again for the answer you posted.

Comment: @vuict a bitmap mask is based on binary pixels: the pixel is masked, or it isn't. If you need a more complex behavior, like having a "mask" with two different color values, then you have to find a further implementation that works for you. For example, you can use a QGraphicsItem subclass that has two MaskItems as children, implement the mouse handling in that parent item (instead of the children) and selectively add/remove regions to/from both children, so that existing pixels on a color mask get removed if they are "written" on the other.